# Google Sheets - iterate over columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

First i'd like to say that i'm completly clueless in excel/sheets programming, but i can program in many other languages - python, C#, matlab, web languages etc.

Im trying to create a google sheet file that will accomodate score prediction for football matches of my club. The table should look something like that: [prediction table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7lAM.png). Each column represent a match, and each row is an individual's prediction.

Each match is played at a different date (once a week), so each week i would like to show 2 graphs:

1. A bar graph like this: [bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u918V.png) - where the title is the header of the column, the vertical & horizontal axes has fixed titles, the horizontal axis values are the cells in the columns, i.e. the predicted results, and the vertical axis count the number of repeatition of each guessed result, i.e accumulated bar graph.
2. a pie graph like this: [pie graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGmqN.png) - which count the number of predictions that predicted either win, lose, or draw to **MY TEAM** (meaning not always the first team or the second team. it depends if my club's name is written in the column's header first or second). I understand that for each column 3 more rows are needed - Win, Draw, Lose which will count that, but i dont know how to approach it. The pie graph's title should be the header of the column, and as in the picture, each color of the graph should specify the percentage and whether it represents a Win, Draw or a lost.

Again, i am a very capable programmer in many other languages, and probably with python i could've finished programming it by the time i finished this post, but i need it to be visible and easy to access by the common man who can't program, hence i chose google sheet. It should be easy enough... So what im asking for is advices on how to implement it with google sheet - which principles of prgramming in excel should i read into before trying to implement this, which function specifically should i look into, and what are good sources to look for those stuff?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: GAS (Google Application Script) is basically JavaScript. So all you need is: JavaScript + object model of SpreadsheetApp https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet . If you're fluent in C# it will be quite easy to figure out. The google documentation has many examples how to make graphs, tables etc. There is the option to use Python + Spreadsheet API -- it's a little more hard way for my taste. But perhaps it will work for you better than native JavaScript, I don't know.

Comment: Rule Spreadsheets with the Python: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

Comment: And how do you mean to input the data into the table? Directly in the Google table web-interface? Or through some Google form? Or you mean to grab the data from some web sites? And where the output (graphs) will go? Will they just please your eyes on the sheet, or they will be sent via email to someone? Automatically or via button/menu? Etc. You need to design the desired workflow, step by step. And I believe SO already has the more of less ready solution for almost all of these steps (but not for the whole workflow of course).

Comment: Hi @YuriKhristich, I will probably insert the info myself or through google form. Each person should have his own row, and if using form, should be either empty if the form never filled, or have the prediction under the specific column. The graphs will be availale for everyone on the group to see through the sheet. Ideally the sheet will be visable to everyone (to see the stats, predictions etc. of everyone else), however only I as admin will have edit privilages. I limit this project to a somewhat simple display and use. if it will be a success i might go out and improve it.